# find if entry exists between two dates in two different columns?

Tags: php, mysql

what is wrong in the code?? I need to allow a new entry only if a record does not exist for the given time period. Like if 1-1-19 to 3-1-19 is there in database new entry for this date range should not happen.

```html
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['book'])) {
require 'db2.php';
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mail=$_POST['emial'];
$mob=$_POST['phone'];
$ddr=$_POST['add'];
$d11=$_POST['date'];
$d12=$_POST['date2'];
$selected_val=$_POST['type'];

if (empty($name)||empty($mail)||empty($mob)||empty($ddr)||empty($d11)||empty($d12)||empty($selected_val)) {

  header("Location: ./booking.php?error=emptyfield");
  exit();
}
elseif (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&& !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$name)) {
  header("Location: ./booking.php?error=entervalidnaneoremail");
  exit();
}
elseif (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $mob)) {
  header("Location: ./booking.php?error=invalidphone");
}
else {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE d1>'$d11' OR d2<'$d12'";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  echo $row;
  if ($row>0) {
    header("Location: ./booking.php?error=Takendate");
      exit();
  }
  else {
      $sql="INSERT INTO book(name, email, no, adr, d1, d2, type) VALUES('$name','$mail','$mob','$ddr','$d11','$d12','$selected_val')" ;
      mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  }
}
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Your code is insecure. See about prepared statements

Comment: And presumably you mean '2019-01-03' !

Comment: Also, you're logic is flawed. What if you B inserts the book while user A is checking?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `AND` instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your dates (`$d11 and $d12`) should be in format `yyyy-mm-dd` so they meet the standar date format for mysql.

Then you need to change this sentence:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE d1>'$d11' OR d2<'$d12'";
```

and use an AND instead of OR like this:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE d1>'$d11' AND d2<'$d12'";
```

and last, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection